# C# replace everything inbetween these tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I want to override a meta-description tag if someone is on a product page of my site.

```
<meta name="description" content=" " />
```

The CMS I am using has this code in the pre-render method of its page template:

```
this.ltlTags.Text = this.HeaderTags;
```

This populates the header with meta tags, CSS tags, script tags and all that.

I want to say something like this:

```
this.ltlTags.Text = this.HeaderTags.Replace(
    "everything inside the content attribute of the meta tag", "with this text");
```

In c# is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure you've provided enough information to answer this question. What is in `this.HeaderTags`? If it contains multiple tags, how are they delimited, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
this.ltlTags.Text = Regex.Replace(this.HeaderTags,
    "content=\"[^\"]*\"", "content=\"" + yourStuff + "\"");
```

It basically replaces `content="<anything>"` with `content="<yourStuff>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the whole tag? And by that I mean

```
this.ltlTags.Text = this.HeaderTags.Replace("<meta name=\"description\" content=\" \" />",
                          "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"new text here\" />");
```